# Puppet print out messages

Tags: puppet

Is there a way to print out messages to the console before executing a command in puppet. For example, let's say my manifest has:

```
exec {
    command => 'mycommandhere'
}
```

I would like to print a message that says 'Running my command'. Is there an easy way to do this, other than calling another command before it that does the print out?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just call puppet with the `--debug` option?

Comment: Didn't think of that -- I'm still pretty new to puppet. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just chain two resources together:

```
notify { 'some-command':
  message => 'some-command is going to be executed now'
}

exec { 'some-command':
  command => '/path/to/some-command',
}

Notify['some-command'] -> Exec['some-command']
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to write your puppet manifest to print a message exactly before your exec resource other than making it a part of the exec. For the general case of printing messages, look at [notify](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#notify). For your specific case, perhaps running puppet in verbose or debug mode will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `notice()` or `warning()` (depending on what you want to tell the user)

```
notice( 'some-command is going to be executed now' )
```

and then simply `exec` right after that line.